# How to get the email id of user company and administrator in email template in odoo

Tags: xml, email, odoo-8, email-templates

Currently i am developing a module to book rooms. When a user book a room, an automatic mail should send to administrator. For this purpose i need to get the email id of the user company and administrator email id in my email templte. How can i do that.

This is my template..

```
<record id="send_request" model="email.template">
        <field name="name">Request Notification</field>
        <field name="email_from">${ }</field>
        <field name="subject">Room request </field>
        <field name="email_to" >${ }</field>
        <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
        <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                    <title>STPI Room Request </title>
                    <style> 
                        span.oe_mail_footer_access {
                            display:block;    
                            text-align:center;
                            color:grey;                                
                        }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>
                    Dear Sir,
                    </p>
                    <br> <p>My company, ${ } would like to use the Room for the specified duration. Kindly concider our request for the use of conference/board room.</p>
                    <br/>
                    <p>
                    Thanks and Regards,
                    <br/>
                     ${ }
                    </p>
                </body>
            </html>
            ]]>
            </field>
    </record>
```

In email_from, i need to get the user company email id and in email_to i need to get the admin email ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email emplate having the **object** which is global entity for entire Email Template.

You can get the object as your current model for the email template which is attached to it.
It means that you can get the of particular model which is based on your 
**model_id** attribute.

**For Example :**

```
 <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
```

hear you can get the **object**  as sale.order model so need to add separate logic for that.

for that object you can access all the fields which are related with that module (like sale.order)

likes..

object.user_id.email

object.company_id.email and so on ..

You can also refers  the sale.order template and many more in addons modules

I hope my answer may helpful for you  :)

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. Thank you. One more thing, How will i get the administrator email id. (Administrator email id is specified in the user option in settings. )

Comment: just make a method which will return the admin email in your model and call that method in your email template some things like object.your_method_name()

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use like this.
because when you use like this then it will take email id from your current object.

${object.email_id_field_name}